# Ubuntu 12.04, asus f550c : it do not go in power save mode

Tags: 12.04, power-management, shutdown, asus, battery

If I remove the charger from my laptop asus f550c, it do not go in power save mode, as I can see from the applet [CPU frequency scaling indicator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/indicator-cpufreq/)

Indeed, usually if I suspend the laptop, it has very short period of autonomy: no more than 2 hours, usually when I recover it from suspend it is already off.
Even if I hibernate it, the battery duration is not what it should be.

I add the fact that during the sleep mode the temperature of the laptop increase (longer is the sleep mode, more the temperature increase).

Any suggestion?